# HashMap: Getting only the last inserted item

Tags: java, android, json, hashmap

I'm trying to iterate my hashmap using this:

```
public HashMap<String,String> getDj(){

    try {
        HashMap<String,String> getDjname = new HashMap<String,String>();
        JSONArray dj_listArray = mJsonObject.getJSONArray("dj_list");
        for (int i = 0; i < dj_listArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject getDjsched = dj_listArray.getJSONObject(i);
            getDjname.put("host_name", getDjsched.getString("host_name"));
            getDjname.put("host_image_url", getDjsched.getString("host_image_url"));
            getDjname.put("host_info_url", getDjsched.getString("host_info_url"));

       }
        Log.e("djlist",""+getDjname);

        return getDjname;


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;

}
```

then im trying to get this using recyclerview:

```
holder.mDj.setText(schedDetailPosition.get(position).getDj().get("host_name"));
```

but the problem is, it does not iterate. it gets only the last item, it display only one.

Comment: Well, you're calling `setText` ... as the name says, it sets the text. What might happen if you call it a second time? Right, it sets the content to a different text and "erasing" the previous one. And since there is no text which replaces the last one, it is the only text that remains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. create custom class/ model to hold the data.
2. `HashMap<String,Object> getDjname = new HashMap<String,Object>();`
   and put unique value as *key* and the whole model as a *value*.

Check below code snippet:

```
JSONArray dj_listArray = mJsonObject.getJSONArray("dj_list");
for (int i = 0; i < dj_listArray.length(); i++) {
    CustomModel model = new CustomModel();
    JSONObject getDjsched = dj_listArray.getJSONObject(i);
    model.host_name = getDjsched.getString("host_name");
    model.host_image_url =getDjsched.getString("host_image_url");
    model.host_info_url= getDjsched.getString("host_info_url"));
    getDjname.put(i, model);
}
```

Comment: Ahh i got it! Thankyou im gonna try this.

Comment: If this answer helps you to fix the issue please "accept it" as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Hashmap can hold only one value against one key. Everytime you are iterating ,you are replacing previous value with new value for that key.

You may consider using list of Hashmap. If you need multiple values.